# Is there a module that can hide sidebars and expand them when required?

Tags: 7, blocks

I need a more space in the centre of the web page but the side bars take up too much space.

Is there a module that can place the sidebars in a single block that can be expanded and contracted as necessary? What I have in mind is something like http://drupal.org/project/admin, but one that contains all the sidebar content. Context is not suitable here as this should be available all the time.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Jquery. Search for jquery show/ hide or toggle and then apply this to the containers you want to hide and have a tab as a toggle handle.

Comment: Apart the fact the question is asking for a module to use, if the answer is "google for [search term]" it is a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [there is a module for that](http://drupal.org/project/collapsiblock), and it makes each block collapsible.

Comment: I use collapsiblock but I need the whole sidebar to be collapsed, not just the individual blocks. The labelling should also be vertical, so that it doesn't intrude into the working area.

Comment: I think the other answer give a good solution; I would go with that.

Comment: The other answer would be a solution, if it showed the code to use.